# Printing lines in a file from match to match

Tags: text-processing

What's a good way to print all lines in a file from the line containing `^# fish,` to (but not including) the next line containing `^#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With AWK:

```
awk '/^#/ { inblock = 0 }; /^# fish/ { inblock = 1 }; inblock'
```

This will actually print all blocks starting with `# fish`. To stop after the first block:

```
awk 'inblock && /^#/ { exit }; /^# fish/ { inblock = 1 }; inblock'
```

Both variants work by setting a variable `inblock` to 1 when processing lines in the interesting block; the last `inblock` statement applies the default action (print the current line) when `inblock` is 1.

Comment: Thanks!  I wonder why reversing the order of the two first commands doesn't work.

Comment: The order is important, because `/^#/` matches on `# fish` too — so if you swap the two commands, `inblock` gets set to 1 then back to 0 immediately.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

The regex repeatedly looks for chunks that begin at the `line boundary` `# fish` and ends at the shortest (non-greedy) `#` adjacent to a newline or at the very end of file itself. The matching portion is then printed out.

```
perl -l -0777ne 'print $& while /^#\sfish.+?(?=\n(?:#|\z))/msg' yourfile


sed -e '
   /^# fish/!d;          # havent yet seen the fish, so skip
   $b; N;                # seen the fish so grab the next line unless its the last in which case promptly show and quit
   /\n#/!s/^/\n/;        # not seen a line with "#" so go read next
   /^\n/D;               # 
   h;                    # whole block /# fish/.../#/ with us now
      s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/;  # remove the last line, i.e., trailing # line
      p;                 # show the block now
   g;                    # retrieve orig unmodified block
   s/.*\n/\n/; D;        # keep the last line and go back for more...
' yourfile
```

Comment: This was faster than the accepted answer.